# How can I get the current HttpContext in a SeriLog Sink?

Tags: c#, httpcontext, asp.net-core-2.0, serilog

I'm creating my own SeriLog sink implementing `ILogEventSink` using the [Building a Simple Sink](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Developing-a-sink) example with the intent of logging some information from the users claims. To get access to HttpContext in Core, I'd normally inject in an instance of `IHttpContextAccessor` but the example shows creating an instance of the sink in an extension method e.g.

```
public class MySink : ILogEventSink
{
    private readonly IFormatProvider _formatProvider;

    public MySink(IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        _formatProvider = formatProvider;
    }

    public void Emit(LogEvent logEvent)
    {
        // How to get HttpContext here?
    }
}

public static class MySinkExtensions
{
    public static LoggerConfiguration MySink(
              this LoggerSinkConfiguration loggerConfiguration,
              IFormatProvider formatProvider = null)
    {
        return loggerConfiguration.Sink(new MySink(formatProvider));
    }
}
```

... then to use the sink ...

```
var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Information()
    .WriteTo.MySink()
    .CreateLogger();
```

How can I get access to the current HttpContext in the Emit method of the sink? Or is it possible to have the sink created by the DI framework for example?!

I have an MVC site running Asp.Net Core 2 framework against .Net 4.6.2 runtime using Serilog.AspNetCore v2.1.0.

**Update - Workaround**

After the pointer from @tsimbalar I created middleware similar to the code below. In my `StartUp.Configure` method I add it using `app.UseMiddleware<ClaimsMiddleware>();` *after* the app authentication step has happened (otherwise there will be no claims loaded).

```
public class ClaimsMiddleware
{
    private static readonly ILogger Log = Serilog.Log.ForContext<ClaimsMiddleware>();
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public ClaimsMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(next));
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContext));

        // Get values from claims here
        var myVal = httpContext
                .User
                .Claims
                .Where(x => x.Type == "MyVal")
                .Select(x => x.Value)
                .DefaultIfEmpty(string.Empty)
                .SingleOrDefault();

        using (LogContext.PushProperty("MyVal", myVal))
        {
            try
            {
                await next(httpContext);
            }

            // Never caught, because `LogException()` returns false.
            catch (Exception ex) when (LogException(httpContext, ex)) { }
        }
    }

    private static bool LogException(HttpContext httpContext, Exception ex)
    {
        var logForContext = Log.ForContext("StackTrace", ex.StackTrace);

        logForContext.Error(ex, ex.Message);

        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE**
I think you may want to look at this article : http://mylifeforthecode.github.io/enriching-serilog-output-with-httpcontext-information-in-asp-net-core/

The idea is to register a custom middleware that will add all the *contextual* information to the current `LogContext` during the request.

For it to work you must configure your logger with

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
      // snip ....MinimumLevel.Debug()
      .Enrich.FromLogContext()                
      // snip ...
.CreateLogger();
```

This article by Nicholas Blumhardt may also help : https://blog.getseq.net/smart-logging-middleware-for-asp-net-core/

---

**WARNING - Solution below does not work in this case**

*The solution below cannot work if the logger is registered early (in Program.Main() )*

First of all, if you want to add extra information attached to the logged event, I believe what you want is an [Enricher](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Enrichment).

You could then :

- Register [IHttpContextAccessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.ihttpcontextaccessor?view=aspnetcore-2.0) into your ServiceCollection (for instance, using [`AddHttpContextAccessor()`](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/pull/947)) : `services.AddHttpContextAccessor();`
- Create an implementation of `ILogEventEnricher` that accepts `IHttpContextAccessor` in its constructor
- When configuring your logger, inject `IHttpContextAccessor` (by adding an argument of type `IHttpContextAccessor` to `Startup.Configure()`
- Add this enricher to your logger

The **enricher** could look something like https://github.com/serilog-web/classic/blob/master/src/SerilogWeb.Classic/Classic/Enrichers/ClaimValueEnricher.cs .

And you would **configure** your logger like this :

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .EnrichWith(new MyEnricher(contextAccessor))
                .WriteTo.Whatever()
                .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: Thanks @tsimbalar. In the **configure** step you are passing the `contextAccessor` into an instance of a `MyEnricher` object. This isn't using dependency injection so how would I be getting the context if I'm configuring logging in the Program Main method before Startup (and subsequently `ConfigureServices`) has been called?

Comment: oh yes, if you are in Program Main , that cannot work .... mmmm not sure how that would work

Comment: Thanks @tsimbalar. I had played around with a middleware solution previously with varying degrees of success. I was hoping there was a better way but I'll go revisit that and update ...

Comment: I had similar issue. Solved by writing Middleware as was suggested here. Might be useful to someone else: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Enrichers.AspNetCore.HttpContext

Answer (score 4):

I have been struggling trying to do the same and I finally found a proper solution.

Do not add the enricher when creating the Logger. You will have to add the enricher in the middleware where you can access the `IServiceProvider`. The key is that `LogContext` has a method, `Push`, that can add an enricher:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
{
    IServiceProvider serviceProvider = httpContext.RequestServices;
    using (LogContext.Push(new LogEnricher(serviceProvider))) {
        await _next(httpContext);
    }
}
```

In the `ConfigureServices`, I add a `services.AddScoped<HttpContextToLog>()` call.

Then, I populate the `HttpContextToLog` object in several places, accessing it like this:

```
HttpContextToLog contextToLog = _serviceProvider.GetService<HttpContextToLog>();
```

in the `Enrich` method, in an `IActionFilter`, in an `IPageFilter`, etc.